# Can i use a Firebase token (JWT) to identify a user with an expire date > than 1 hour?

Tags: node.js, firebase, web-services, google-cloud-firestore, jwt

I'm using **Cloud Firestore for Firebase** to store informations about a Rest API Service written in NodeJs.

So, every request to Node will ask to Firebase informations about the service and, for first, it will **authorize** the request.

I thought that use an user generated JWT will be the best solution because the client have to simply include the JWT in his requests to authorize itself.

A **Firebase JWT** is related to the uid of the user that generates it.
Obviously, there'll be a control panel where the user can log in with email/pw and generate the JWT, and then the JWT will be included in his client system, for example like simple APIs that requires an API Key to identify the user and to work.

So, the idea appears to work good but i noticed that the Firebase JWTs expire in **only 1 hour!**
The user have to log-in to the control panel every hour to re-generate the JWT. That's not so friendly.

How can avoid this problem? How can i make the JWT expires in more than only 1 hour?

Comment: You could use the [`getidtoken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken) method but it is not clear to me if the user is constantly interacting with the node.js or if your plan is to sore the JWT for long term periods... Maybe adding a diagram detailing your app architecture would help.

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec, thx for the reply! My plan is to store the JWT for long term periods. The user won't interact with the browser and with node.js. The idea is to use the JWT as an API Key to authenticate the Https requests to the node.js server (that communicate with Firebase)

Comment: The user can only interact with the browser for generate the JWT. Then, he has to paste the JWT in the header of the https requests (as a Bearer token) to authenticate the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts#required_claims):

> The maximum lifetime of a token is 24 hours + skew.

[...]

> with a skew of up to 10 minutes.

That means you cannot use these tokens forever, which kind of makes sense.

I looked at [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) and found:

> The time, in seconds since the UNIX epoch, at which the token expires. It can be a maximum of 3600 seconds later than the iat.
> Note: this only controls the time when the custom token itself expires. But once you sign a user in using signInWithCustomToken(), they will remain signed in into the device until their session is invalidated or the user signs out.

Perhaps you can do something with the `signInWithCustomToken()` as once logged in it expires only when the user is invalidated or signs out, but I believe the best course of action would be to look for another approach.